# Cakephp: How to authenticate user?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have user form with fields user name and password which stored in user table in one database 
and one other database which have only user_id

I want to authenticate user_id

if user_id is match in both table then login

Comment: when you say "other database" do you mean table?

Comment: Is it other database or other table ,which has user_id as foreign key???